# Replacing Xcode 6 default Launchscreen with a Custom animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a animation (in swift) that I want to display while the app loads.
I am assuming I must  override Xcode 6 default Launch Screen to do so.

My question is how do we override the default LaunchScreen in Xcode to allow a custom launch as in my animation.

Any feedback appreciated.

Thanks
Ciaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Apple doesn't recommend having these types of launch screens.  But to answer your questions, make the first UIController of your app have this custom animation and then after the animation is done, have it segue to your app's main screen.

Comment: OK thanks, apple don't recommend but do they turn back an app if you override a Launch Screen i.e. does to breach the guideline

Comment: anyhow doesn't matter, just ran the animation after the launch screen